# Except homepage other links are not working for Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have done the new setup of drupal in localhost folder @ `htdocs/my-folder/`.
When I tried to load the project in url then its homepage loading properly but when I click on any links then its redirecting to blank page with below warning:

```
`Deprecated: assert(): Calling assert() with a string argument is deprecated in D:\xampp\htdocs\law-drupal\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager.php on line 151

Deprecated: assert(): Calling assert() with a string argument is deprecated in D:\xampp\htdocs\law-drupal\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager.php on line 151`
```

Since I am doing Drupal setup for very first time, So I am not getting where I am making mistake. Why except homepage other links are not working for Drupal?

Please Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

it is because **Drupal 8.4 isn't compatible with PHP 7.2 because of stuff like this. But it's been fixed in 8.5, which is coming soon.**

So you have two solutions

- Update your drupal version
- Downgrade your PHP version to 5+

Comment: Done this, still same issue. I tried by clearing cache as well but no luck @Yusef

Comment: @MohammedSabir what exactly you did?  downgrade the php or upgrade the drupal?

Comment: downgraded the php

Comment: @MohammedSabir to which version?

Comment: php 7.0 version

Comment: @MohammedSabir, unfortunately, you need to downgrade to version less than 7, 
So I suggest updating the Drupal core ( while finally, you need to update it later)

Comment: I cant update it, since Its the code provided by client.

Comment: @MohammedSabir So downgrade php to php5

Answer (score 0):

htaccess file which may not be present
Generally htaccess file is hidden and to see them use $ll command to long list all files.
If present check the configurations inside the .htaccess file